# Making sure D rawRead()s a big endian struct from a file

Tags: struct, d, endianness

I'm trying to build a simple PNG reader, but with macOS being a little endian system and PNG being a big endian format, I'm running into a big (for me, at least, I'm new to D) problem.

Have a bunch of code first:

```
static enum IHDR_BitDepth: ubyte {
    BitDepth1  = 1,
    BitDepth2  = 2,
    BitDepth4  = 4,
    BitDepth8  = 8,
    BitDepth16 = 16
}

static enum IHDR_ColorType: ubyte {
    Greyscale      = 0,
    TrueColor      = 2,
    Indexed        = 3,
    GreyscaleAlpha = 4,
    TrueColorAlpha = 6
}

static enum IHDR_CompressionMethod: ubyte {
    Deflate = 0
}

static enum IHDR_FilterMethod: ubyte {
    Adaptive = 0
}

static enum IHDR_InterlaceMethod: ubyte {
    NoInterlace    = 0,
    Adam7Interlace = 1
}

struct IHDR {
    align(1): // don't pad this struct so .sizeof works properly
    uint Width;
    uint Height;
    IHDR_BitDepth BitDepth;
    IHDR_ColorType ColorType;
    IHDR_CompressionMethod CompressionMethod;
    IHDR_FilterMethod FilterMethod;
    IHDR_InterlaceMethod InterlaceMethod;
}

// further down the file

File file = File(fname, "r");

// stuff

PngHeaders.IHDR ihdr;
file.rawRead((&ihdr)[0..1]);
writeln(ihdr);
```

This last `writeln` outputs this:

> IHDR(1380206665, 570490880, cast(IHDR_BitDepth)0, Greyscale, cast(IHDR_CompressionMethod)1, cast(IHDR_FilterMethod)34, cast(IHDR_InterlaceMethod)8)

which is obviously wrong.

I found [a thread from 2003](https://forum.dlang.org/thread/bfp2vr$156v$1@digitaldaemon.com) where an endianness attribute is being discussed, but it doesn't exist yet.

Is there another easy way to get D to treat the file (or at least the structs) as big endian? I like the ability to just read whole structs from files instead of having to read every value myself, so if there's a way that lets me keep doing that, I'd prefer that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I actually prefer reading files byte by byte anyway, since so many of them have variable length as well as endianness and doing it byte by byte solves both problems. (You can also do helper functions, mixins, attributes, etc to make this simpler.)

But another option would be to keep your struct like you have, but write property functions to do the conversions.

```
struct Header {
    align(1):
    ubyte[4] Width_; // the bytes in the file
    @property int Width() { return bigEndianToNative(Width_); }
    // ditto for the others
   /* snip */
 }
```

And maybe do a setter if you want that. So then you can still slurp it up with rawRead, but accessing the properties converts for you.

There's pros and cons to this but I wanted to answer it as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know you could do that with properties. I just wrote what is probably the ugliest mixin ever, but it's reusable and works.

Answer (score 3):

Use [bigEndianToNative](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_bitmanip.html#bigEndianToNative) i.e. [my png file format module](https://github.com/Devisualization/image/blob/master/source/base/devisualization/image/fileformats/png.d#L312).

Comment: Thanks! It kinda sucks that I can't use structs for this.